# SharePoint Store Errors

Tags: internet, sharepoint-store

In an effort to secure our environment our infrastructure team have prevented our SharePoint application server from accessing the internet.

For a few days everything seemed fine however this morning several users have reported that SharePoint is running slowly, when I checked the logs I found this error:

> The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppStateQueryJobDefinition (ID 831efc0e-03ec-4b16-99d1-931f178d8c5f) threw an exception. More information is included below.
>
> Sorry, we can't seem to connect to the SharePoint Store. Try again in a bit.

I wasn't aware that our SharePoint installation even "called home". How can I stop it attempting to connect to the internet?

I've checked in the following:

- Apps that require accessible internet facing endpoints - Deactivated
- App Management Service - Stopped
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service - Stopped

Is there anything else I have missed or should I get the infrastructure team to re-enable internet access for this server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SPAppStateQueryJobDefinition` is a timer job registered with the title "App State Update" that runs hourly. According to its description in Central Admin its function is to:

> [retrieve] and [apply] updated information on apps from the SharePoint
>   Store, including the availability of updates and disable information.

Basically, it tires to make sure that any apps you have purchased or installed from the SharePoint Store are up to date and updates apps on the farm if needed.

You can turn off the timer job in Central Admin if you aren't using any Store Apps, but I'm not sure if there are any other consequences of turning it off (i.e. impact on other custom apps that are installed in the farm).

Comment: I wasn't able to locate a job called *App Store Update* but there was one called *App State Update* which had `Failed` next to it. I've disabled that. I'll wait a couple of hours to see if that solves my issue.

Comment: This appears to have worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. I've updated the answer so the job name is _App State Update_.