# PowerShell Cmdlet Not Recognised

Tags: powershell, timer-jobs

While researching the timer job [`App State Update`](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163630/sharepoint-store-errors) I was wondering if I could find the URL it accesses so I could retain its functionality by whitelisting that single URL and blocking all other internet access.

I came across the PowerShell command [`Get-SPMarketplaceConnectionSettings`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj219534.aspx). However when I try to run it in the SharePoint Management Console I get the error:

> ```
> Get-SPMarketplaceConnectionSettings : The term
> 'Get-SPMarketplaceConnectionSettings' is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
> + Get-SPMarketplaceConnectionSettings
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-SPMarketplaceConnectionSett
>    ings:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> ```

The TechNet article does not list a usage example. Am I using it wrong? How else could I find out how `App State Update` connects to the internet? Our SharePoint environment is an on-premises installation.

Comment: sharepoint online or on prem?

Comment: On premises, I'll update the question

Comment: are you running remotely or on the server itself ? why dont you use ISE and import the snap in and use it .this gives better view on powershell  commands with help and so on.

Comment: I am running it on the server itself as an administrator. I'll try the ISE.

Answer (score 0):

there is another command, which will do the same thing.

[Get-SPAppStoreConfiguration](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/jj730450.aspx) Returns app SharePoint Store settings.

Comment: This command just returns `Enabled | True`

Comment: Yes, if you read the description a if both commands are same

Comment: However it does not return any relevant information.